# VB.NET Datatable to Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm creating an application which allows you to manage various data. The application is designed to work in a network, and thus in multi-user. For this reason I decided to trust the Datatable.

I have a class created by me for the management of operations MYSQL Database but now I still can not create a streamlined process to send the datatable to MySQL database.
Currently I am so

```
    Dim SQLStm As String
    'variable for sql query
    Dim SQLManager As New ER.DB.ERMysql

    For Each Riga In Datatable.Rows
        'example query
        SQLStm = "INSERT INTO test(Name,Phone)VALUES(Riga("Name"),Riga("Phone"))"
        Try
            Dim CMD As New MySqlCommand
            CMD.Connection = connection
            CMD.CommandText = SQLStm
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next


End Sub
```

or skim all the rows and gradually sending to the database. There is a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks to all

Comment: This is just one example, can not be compiled because the query is explanatory. Anyway, with the original query it works !

Comment: You can use `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlCommandBuilder` to update the database. And in case `DataAdapter` is not feasible then create `Parameterized SQL` statements to perform insertion/updation.

Comment: Thanks, i will search on Google for CommandBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best way to do this would be via XML. Convert the datatable to xml format and pass it through to a procedure which accepts an XML. This saves the process from running once per every line within a datatable, and it is all done in one go. The current way you are doing this would not scale well for large data sets, but XML would scale far better.

Answer (score 0):

instead performing a db insert for each row, build the whole query string first and then perform it as one large INSERT command. It's much faster.